# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Replication Factor and Retention Problem at Runtime

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, retention, replication-factor

I have a spring boot project using Kafka. I configured it with Spring Cloud Stream Kafka auto configuration. I want to create my topics automatically with 3 replicas and 1 day retention. For this I added replication factor and retention.ms to my application.yml like below:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          replicationFactor: 3
        default:
          consumer:
            topic:
              properties:
                retention.ms: 86400000
          producer:
            topic:
              properties:
                retention.ms: 86400000
```

Actually these work fine for me, topics create as 3 replicas with 1 day retention but when I delete a topic while application running, this topic creates automatically without replica and retention. Anyone know the reason for this? What should I do to create my topics with 3 replicas and 1 day retention at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the broker's `auto.create.topics.enable` property to `false`.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_auto.create.topics.enable

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. Now topics are created at the starting but not at runtime.